# Razor expression not evaluating right

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc, razor

We have a strange behavior on some servers. We have an HTML div with a "data-" value evaluated within a Razor expression :

```
<div id="adresseData" data-iseditable="@(user.CheckAccess("Scope", "PermissionX"))" />
```

The CheckAccess method returns a bool value. On local machines and old servers, evverything works fine and the HTML results on the browser looks like this :

```
<div id="adresseData" data-iseditable="True"></div>
```

But since we migrated on new servers, we have a weird behavior. The value is a string that is the exact same as the data- expression :

```
<div id="adresseData" data-iseditable="data-iseditable"></div>
```

We looked everywhere in our code to see if some client script was doing the switch but didn't find anything. Did anyone ever encountered anything like this ?

For info, we are targeting the .NET framework version 4.5 and we're using client javascript framework KendoUI

**EDIT :** Seems like the values are evaluated correctly when the condition is directly used or inside a "If" statement, but it only happens when we're assigning the value to an attribute.

Comment: Out of curiosity - what is the value of `@(user.CheckAccess("Scope", "PermissionX"))` - try debugging it/ printing it the View to see what it returns.

Comment: Good idea, we'll try it ASAP (I don't have access rights on DEV environment server, don't ask me why...). We've found some other problems that may suggest a bug with the encoding.

Comment: Are you checking the generated HTML, or the DOM?

Comment: The generated HTML within the Chrome debug tool and the DOM.Both values are the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turn out it was a problem with the MVC version.